# Simulate click of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Have a custom map (http://atlas.nrcan.gc.ca/site/english/toporama/index.html), and it has zoom button. This zoom has no inline onclick event.

I need to have a div (outside the map) and when it is clicked => should simulate zoom in effect.

I tried this:

```
onclick="$('#OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_3_zoomin').click()"
```

but it has no effect.

The zoom effect is sort of complex, and I don't want so dig the source to find what function is called to zoom. The only thing I need is to simulate click, something like a shortcut to the zoom button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not Google Maps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The api has methods built in

The OpenLayers Map object is stored in a global variable named `map`

To zoom in:

```
map.zoomIn();
```

To zoom out:

```
map.zoomOut();
```

Comment: yes this works, thank you! but what if it's not related to maps and I want to simulate a click using a remote div?

Comment: `$("#foo").trigger("click");`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('#OpenLayers\\.Control\\.PanZoomBar_3_zoomin').trigger("click")` in a function

***EDIT:*** You need to doubleslash the periods so you aren't trying to select classes.

Comment: the escaping is right, but click() does not work for zoom button... though .html('aaaa') will work...

Comment: Yes, I noticed that myself. @epascarello has the right answer, tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_3_zoomin').click(function(){Do stuff here})
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The zoom effect is sort of complex, and I don't want so dig the source to find what function is called to zoom. The only thing I need is to simulate click, something like a shortcut to the zoom button.

Comment: you can call whatever method you would like to in the inner click handler and should be fine.

Comment: I don't think an event handler will solve the issue of triggering a click on an element ?

Comment: You will need to look into the open layers map api and get your method. I think @epascarello had it there for you.

Comment: You accepted an answer that did not tell you how to add an onclick to a div. You should, for relevance, accept an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming there is a function somewhere that initiates the zoom event (depending on where the map is coming from). You should be able to re-use it with your own click function.

```
$('#myElement').click(function(){

//callback to zoom function

});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to simulate a click I would look into `.trigger();`

```
$('#OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_3_zoomin').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: The zoom effect is sort of complex, and I don't want so dig the source to find what function is called to zoom. The only thing I need is to simulate click, something like a shortcut to the zoom button.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer.. Maybe give `.trigger()` a try.